# Error about non-requested dependency when trying to build an Android lib using CMake

Tags: android, ssl, cmake

I'm trying to build an Android lib with Gradle and CMake. I'm adding OpenSSL like that:

```
add_library(Ssl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Crypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        /Users/user/dev/android_openssl/static/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a)
```

But the build is failing with this message:

```
ninja: error: 'Ssl-NOTFOUND', needed by 'lib/libmylib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

In build.ninja file the lib is appearing as is: Ssl-NOTFOUND before libssl.a with the right path

Any idea about why I have this dependency which is created by CMake?

EDIT

The issue was a bad target property:

```
add_library(Ssl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        /Users/user/dev/android_openssl/static/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a)
```

Comment: A typo? You add imported library target `Ssl` and set properties for target `Crypto`. Shouldn't that be target `Ssl` too?

Comment: @vre omg. It was!! Around one hour looking for the issue. Thanks!